# error while trying to send bulk emails using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to send some emails using ruby script and i get error after sending to about a few emails then gives the error as shown below. Note: i'm using office365 as smtp provider.
this is the initial folder containing the scripts below
[folder containing the scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtyzb.png)

this is the email handler script below

```
require './savmail/lib/mail.rb'

require './utils.rb'

RECIPIENT_HOLDER = "%0%"

module EmailHandler
    def self.format_email(email: '', recipient: '')
        # fill in all the placeholders
        return email.gsub(RECIPIENT_HOLDER, recipient)
    end


    def self.compose_email(recipient: nil, sender: nil, sender_name: nil, subject: '', html: nil, text: '')
        # Save recipient so other threads don't touch
        Utils.save_recipient(email: recipient)
        text_content = text
        html_content = format_email(email: html, recipient: recipient)

        mail = Mail.new do
            to      recipient
            from    sender_name + " <" + sender + ">"
            subject subject
        end

        text_part = Mail::Part.new do
            body text_content
        end

        html_part = Mail::Part.new do
            content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
            body html_content
        end

        mail.text_part = text_part
        mail.html_part = html_part

        return { 'msg'=> mail, 'recipient'=> recipient, 'sender'=> sender }
    end

    def self.email_login(sender_tuple: [], mail: '')
        smtp_login = sender_tuple[0]
        smtp_password = sender_tuple[1]
        smtp_host = sender_tuple[2]
        smtp_port = sender_tuple[3]
        limit = sender_tuple[4]

        begin
            # server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
            # server.starttls()
            # server.login(smtp_login, smtp_password)
            options = { 
                :address              => smtp_host,
                :port                 => smtp_port,
                # :domain               => 'your.host.name',
                :user_name            => smtp_login,
                :password             => smtp_password,
                :authentication       => 'login',
                # :enable_starttls_auto => true  
            }
            mail.delivery_method :smtp, options

            return mail
        rescue Exception => e
            puts 'Failed to Login to ' + smtp_login
            return false
        end
    end

    def self.send_email(payload: nil, sender_address: nil, recipient: nil, server: nil)
        begin
            payload.deliver
            puts 'Sent from '+sender_address+' to '+recipient
            return payload
        rescue Exception => e
            Utils.save_recipient(email: recipient, failed: true)
            puts 'Email Failed to Send from '+sender_address+' to '+ recipient
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

then this is the main sender script

```
# from email_handler import compose_email, send_email, email_login
require './email_handler.rb'
require './utils.rb'
include EmailHandler

# Change Subject for all emails here
$custom_sender_name = "Africonso Tradings"
$custom_sender_email = "admin@africonsotradings.com"
$email_subject = "test mail."
$threads_total = 10

# These files have to exist
$army_file_path = './army.txt'
$email_file_path = './msg.html'
$senders_file_path = './senders.txt'


def mail_savage(recipients, senders, payload, custom_sender_email, custom_sender_name, email_subject, active_limit: nil, active_server: nil)
    ''' Login as one sender and send emails until the limit is reached or the email stops working,
    then do the same for the rest
    '''
    # Get first recipient from array
    sender = senders[0]

    # sender_email, smtp_password, smtp_host, smtp_port, limit = sender
    sender_email = sender[0]
    smtp_password = sender[1]
    smtp_host = sender[2]
    smtp_port = sender[3]
    limit = sender[4]
    mail_limit = active_limit or limit.to_i

    # if !recipients
    #     return true
    # end

    # Make sure we haven't emailed this user before
    for recipient in recipients
        if Utils.is_recipient_saved(email: recipient)
            # Move to next email if sent already
            next
        end

        # compose email
        # mail, recipient_email, csender_email = compose_email(recipient=recipient, sender=sender_email, sender_name=custom_sender_name, subject=email_subject, html=payload)
        mail_data = EmailHandler.compose_email(recipient: recipient, sender: sender_email, sender_name: custom_sender_name, subject: email_subject, html: payload)
        mail = mail_data['msg']
        recipient_email = mail_data['recipient']
        csender_email = mail_data['sender']


        # Login as sender if fail dump sender
        server = false
        while server == false do
            server = EmailHandler.email_login(sender_tuple: sender, mail: mail)
        end

        # Send email
        # print('Sending from %s to %s' % (sender_email, recipient))
        if !EmailHandler.send_email(payload: server, sender_address: sender_email, recipient: recipient_email, server: server)
            # email failed to send
            # Call it again without this sender and with the current limit
            server = EmailHandler.email_login(sender_tuple: sender, mail: server)
        end
    end

    # if server
    #     server.finish
    # end
    return true
end


def main()
    ''' Send email from msg.html to all addresses in army.txt
    with the addresses in senders.txt
    '''

    senders_all = Utils.get_sender_addresses(path: $senders_file_path)
    recipients_all = Utils.get_army_addresses(path: $army_file_path)
    html_content = Utils.get_email_content(path: $email_file_path)

    threads = []

    for th in 0..$threads_total-1
        threc = recipients_all[th..recipients_all.length-1]

        if threc != nil && threc.length > 0

            threads << Thread.new {
                if th == 0
                    sleep 2
                end
                mail_savage(recipients_all, senders_all, html_content, $custom_sender_email, $custom_sender_name, $email_subject, active_limit: nil, active_server: nil)
            }
        end
        # thread.join
        # thread.start()
    end

    threads.each do |t|
        t.join
    end
end

main
```

so when i try to send the mail, first it sends one mail multiple times then the rest email fails as shown below
[cmd main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYlkv.jpg)

then this happens
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBDYp.jpg)

Now my question is why the emails are failing after sending a very few mails successfully. i think there is an error somewhere in the script.
Any help?

Now i have added the puts e and i am getting the error code below. Please note that it sends about 20 mails and the rest fails.
[error i get now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7bjs.jpg)

Also how can i make the code to accept a different smtp apart from 365?

Comment: Can you please include code snippets rather than images?

Comment: In your `self.send_email` method, you `rescue Exception => e` but don't actually display what the exception is. That would be the first thing to do - add a `puts e` somewhere in the `rescue` block and see what the error is. It's going to be pretty difficult to debug without that info.

Comment: @SaraTibbetts i edited the question to show the code. Any help?

Comment: @supremebeing7 I could not understand you. Can you please show me what you mean?

Comment: You are rescuing an Exception and storing in a variable `e`. After the line `puts 'Email Failed to Send from '+sender_address+' to '+ recipient`, add the lines `puts e` and `puts e.backtrace`. That will print the variable with the error that was rescued, along with the backtrace. Ref: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html

Comment: @africonso you should do a `puts e` wherever you are doing `rescue => e` to check what exception is being rescued

Comment: @supremebeing7 I have edited the question showing the error message i get.

Comment: @anonn023432 I have edited the question and added the error message i get.

Comment: Added an answer based on the error message you received

Answer (score 0):

The relevant piece from your error log looks to be the `550 5.1.8 Access denied, bad outbound sender`. As you mentioned you are using office 365 as your smtp provider, there is a post on Microsoft's support site that suggests this is due to your [sending address being suspected of sending spam](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/550-518-Access-Denied-Bad-bf336c1b).

Since you are trying to send a number of emails in quick succession, this seems like the issue you are running into.

If it's the same email message going to all emails, you may consider sending one message with all addresses as BCC. Otherwise, you may need to check with your Office 365 admin to see if there are settings you can tweak. You may also consider using a transactional email provider (i.e. SendGrid, Mailchimp, or even what appears to be Microsoft's transactional email system, [Dynamics Marketing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-marketing/developers-guide/dn659824(v=mdm.8))) that is built to handle these types of things, and which often have batch mail actions that won't tie up your server.

Comment: Thank you. i finally figured the problem is from the smtp provider. Now looking at the script, how do i make it accept other smtp providers because it only works with outlook smtp.

Comment: It looks like you are configuring your smtp provider based on values in a `senders.txt` file, so will need to change those values.